# How to solve x in y for both are vectors?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inner-products, matrix-equations, positive-definite

Solve $x$ in $y$ with the following equation $$-y+x^Tyx=0$$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. It could be verfied that the solution is  $x=\frac{y}{||y||}$, could someone help explain how to achieve such a solution.

Comment: Depending on $y$ there are two or infinite many solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y$ is the zero vector then this equation holds for *all* $x$ and we're done, so now let's only consider the case where $y$ is nonzero.  We have
$$(x^\top y) x = y$$
Notice that $x^\top y$ is a scalar.  So $x$ must be a scalar multiple of $y$ for this equation to have any chance of holding.  Which?  Set $x = \lambda y$; then the equation says
$$(\lambda  y^\top y) \lambda y = y$$
Which means that
$$\lambda^2 (y^\top y) = 1$$
so
$$\lambda = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\big(y^\top y\big)}} = \frac{1}{||y||}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
-y + x^\top y x  = 0 \iff \\
y = (x \cdot y) \, x \quad (*)
$$
If $y = 0$ then all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are solutions.  If $y \ne 0$ then $x \ne 0$ and we can scalar product multiply both sides of equation $(*)$ by $y$ and get
$$
y \cdot y = \lVert y \rVert_2^2 
= (x \cdot y)^2 \Rightarrow \lVert y \rVert_2 
= \lvert x \cdot y \rvert
$$
where $\lVert . \rVert_2$ is the Euclidean norm and thus
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{sgn}{sgn}
\frac{1}{\lVert y \rVert_2} y
= \frac{x\cdot y}{\lvert x \cdot y \rvert} x
= \sgn(x\cdot y) \, x \Rightarrow \\
x = \pm \frac{1}{\lVert y \rVert_2} y = \pm e_y
$$
where $e_y$ is the unit vector in $y$-direction. So depending on $y$ we have either two or infinite many solutions $x$.